# APIM Generating API from Existing Resource returns 200 constantly

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I am trying to get API Management to forward requests and give me the responses using the template - create from existing App Service

I select my App Service and all of the operations are generated fine

However, no matter what I do, whenever I call any endpoint of the new API I get a 200 response which is totally useless

Please can someone help as this is really frustrating me now

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <rewrite-uri template="@(context.Request.Url.Path.Replace("/pml","/api"))" />
        <set-backend-service id="apim-generated-policy" backend-id="myresource" />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <forward-request />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

Paul

Comment: Did you created a backend entity called myresource in APIM? If so can you please mention the steps followed? If not, can you check this link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.apimanagement/new-azapimanagementbackend?view=azps-9.0.0 to create one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** If you are trying to setup correcly your APIM forwarding to your real App Service:

Set the base-url in your APIM Policy to point to your App service DNS or internal IP (if reacable from APIM):

```
<set-backend-service base-url="https://yourserviceIP" />
<set-backend-service base-url="https://myservice.azurewebsites.net" />
```

Example with JWT:

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized. Access token is missing or invalid.">
            <openid-config url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/yourtenant/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
            <audiences>
                <audience>[AppAudience]</audience>
            </audiences>
            <issuers>
                <issuer>[AppIssuer]</issuer>
            </issuers>
        </validate-jwt>
        <base />
        <set-backend-service base-url="https://myservice.azurewebsites.net" />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

**2.** If you are trying to mock responses just check this tutorial so you can learn how to return other responses than 200:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/mock-api-responses?tabs=azure-portal

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/mock-api-responses?tabs=azure-portal#enable-response-mocking